# Reading a local file in Google App Engine with Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to use go instead of python for my website on google app engine. But I keep getting this error with my script when I test locally.

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

I'm pretty confused, however it will run without error if I comment out

```
channel <- buffer[0:dat]
```

So I must be using channels incorrectly, Any help?

Edit:

This is the working code, many thanks to Kevin Ballard for helping me get this one.

```
package defp

import (
    "fmt"
    "http"
    "os"
)

func getContent(filename string, channel chan []byte) {
    file, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_RDONLY, 0666)
    defer file.Close()
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("FILE FOUND : " + filename + " \n")
        buffer := make([]byte, 16)
        dat, err := file.Read(buffer)
        for err == nil {
            fmt.Printf("herp")
            channel <- buffer[0:dat]
            buffer = make([]byte, 16)
            dat, err = file.Read(buffer)
        }
        close(channel)
        fmt.Printf("DONE READING\n")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("FILE NOT FOUND : " + filename + " \n")
    }
}
func writeContent(w http.ResponseWriter, channel chan []byte) {
    fmt.Printf("ATTEMPTING TO WRITE CONTENT\n")
    go func() {
        for bytes := range channel {
            w.Write(bytes)
            fmt.Printf("BYTES RECEIVED\n")
        }
    }()
    fmt.Printf("FINISHED WRITING\n")
}
func load(w http.ResponseWriter, path string) {
    fmt.Printf("ATTEMPTING LOAD " + path + "\n")
    channel := make(chan []byte, 50)
    writeContent(w, channel)
    getContent(path, channel)
}
func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("HANDLING REQUEST FOR " + r.URL.Path[1:] + "\n")
    load(w, r.URL.Path[1:])
}
func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handle)
}
```

Comment: The panic should give you a backtrace. What line is it actually panic'ing on?

Comment: I tried running your code locally and it didn't panic. Granted, it didn't actually work either, but that's because a) you're trying to write the response in a goroutine instead of synchronously within the handler (just get rid of the `go` before the `writeContent`) and b) you're writing individual bytes as numbers instead of writing the bytes as, well, bytes (change `writeContent` to just use `w.Write(bytes)`). Granted, even with that you'll have thread issues because you're reusing the buffer you're sending to the other channel.

Comment: Did you mean change fmt.Fprint to w.Write(bytes)? (Thanks for the help btw)

Comment: Yes, I did mean to change `fmt.Fprint(w, bytes)` to `w.Write(bytes)`. The former writes the byte array as a sequence of integers, the latter writes it directly as bytes.

Comment: I revised it so that (I hope) it works better, the output from the terminal looks like this:

HANDLING REQUEST FOR file.html
ATTEMPTING LOAD file.html
FILE FOUND : fun.html 
ATTEMPTING TO WRITE CONTENT
DONE READING

Comment: You're still reading from the channel in a goroutine. I haven't looked at how the http package is actually implemented, but from experimentation, once you return from the handler function, the response is written to the wire. By reading from the channel in a goroutine, you're writing your response *after* it's already been sent out, and therefore it doesn't work. You should kill the `go func()` wrapped around the read loop. You also need to `close()` the channel where you print "DONE READING" or the read loop will never terminate.

Comment: Ahh yes, I had just done the close thing and was about to update :). As for killing the go func() that worked perfectly :D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why your program sometimes panics is that it is sometimes writing to `w http.ResponseWriter` after the program exits the `load` function. The `http` package automatically closes the `http.ResponseWriter` when the program exits the handler function. In function `writeContent`, the program will sometimes attempt to write to a closed `http.ResponseWriter`.

BTW: You can make the program source code much smaller if you use the `io.Copy` function.

To always get predictable behavior, make sure that **all work** that you want the program to perform in response to a HTTP request **is done before you exit the handler function**. For example:

```
func writeContent(w http.ResponseWriter, channel chan []byte) {
    fmt.Printf("ATTEMPTING TO WRITE CONTENT\n")
    for bytes := range channel {
            w.Write(bytes)
            fmt.Printf("BYTES RECEIVED\n")
    }
    fmt.Printf("FINISHED WRITING\n")
}

func load(w http.ResponseWriter, path string) {
    fmt.Printf("ATTEMPTING LOAD " + path + "\n")
    channel := make(chan []byte)
    workDone := make(chan byte)
    go func() {
            writeContent(w, channel)
            workDone <- 1 //Send an arbitrary value
    }()
    go func() {
            getContent(path, channel)
            workDone <- 2 //Send an arbitrary value
    }()
    <-workDone
    <-workDone
}

func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("HANDLING REQUEST FOR " + r.URL.Path[1:] + "\n")
    load(w, r.URL.Path[1:])
}
```